# TinyMCE error when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I just updated a client's application with TinyMCE version 4.1.7 and now I am having issues resizing the editor (using the arrow at the bottom right of the editor)

It is failing to resize and Firebug is showing a JS error, "m.css is not a function". The previous version of the code I was using had no such error.

Here's the editor init:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#alert_text',
  content_css : '/styles/foac_mce.css',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager'

                        ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  resize: 'both'
  });
```

Also note I have tried it with and without the resize: 'both' and the same thing happens, I have also tried it with both version 1.6.2 and 1.7 of jQuery and it happens in both. I tried the 1.7 version because that is what they use on their example page.

On that note I have no issues on the TinyMCE example page resizing, it works and I get no errors so I have to think it is a local conflict.

I can't link to the code because it is in an admin area, protected by a username and log in

thanks

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem. I have the sam issue myself

Comment: Nope, never did. I ended up shutting resize off and showed them how to use full screen (which they ended up liking better)

Comment: I "resolved" my problem by dongrading the TinyMCE version to 4.1. 
I haven't been able to determine what was wrong. But the bug was present only in FF. Chrome/IE were working fine.